# Matching words by excluding space and special characters

Tags: excel

I'm trying to match the below words in different cells.

```
shirtsize   shirt size 42

shirt Size  shirt size

shirt-size  shirt size 42

shirt - Size    shirt,size
```

Below is the function i was using but its not giving the expected result.

```js
Function ExactWordInString(Text As String, Word As String) As Boolean
     ExactWordInString = " " & UCase(Text) & " " Like "*[!A-Z]" & UCase(Word) & "[!A-Z]*"
End Function
```

Comment: sorry, but what do you want to achieve, or check, or whatsever? What is passed as Text and Word parameters?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. Please show some example input, desired output, current output, and point out how the current output differs from the desired. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) always helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Function ExactWordInString(Text As String, Word As String) As Boolean
     ExactWordInString = " " & UCase(Text) & " " Like "*[!A-Z]" & UCase(Word) & "[!A-Z]*"
End Function
```

```js
Function ExactWordInString(Text As String, Word As String) As Boolean
     ExactWordInString = " " & UCase(Text) & " " Like "*[!A-Z]" & UCase(Word) & "[!A-Z]*"
End Function
```

Hi all please find the below example.

```js
Column1                 Column2         Result Expected Result
Air Force One         Force         TRUE TRUE
Air Force-One         Force         FALSE TRUE
Air "Force" One         Force         FALSE TRUE
United States Brands United States FALSE TRUE
UnitedStates Brands     United States FALSE TRUE
United-States Brands United States FALSE TRUE
```